# How to visible/invisible launcher icon in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-package-managers

I am creating an application in which i need to hide icon launcher and show icon launcher on request. I used below code to hide launcher icon.

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> // Remove this line from manifest.xml
```

or

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(),
PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

By using these snippet of code, I am only able to hide application icon.

***In order to show i used these code snippet***

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(),
PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

and

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(),
PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

But none of them is effecting or i am not able to retrieve launcher icon back programmatically. Please suggest me how can i achieve this task.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see the difference between last two code snippets.

Comment: @gunar : last line of code , you can see the difference :)

Comment: @gunar: PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT and PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED

Comment: Now I see it ... I need to change my glasses :)